# Excellent Service example baffles me

Tags: android, service

I'm reading "Pro Android 2" which contains an excellent Service example as follows:

```
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class TestService1 extends Service {
        private static final String TAG = "TestService1";

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
            super.onCreate();
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBind");
            return null;
        }
     }
```

I also added the service definition entry as a child of:

```
    <application> in my AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

    <service android:name="TestService1"></service>
```

The book then says:"The next obvious question is how to do you call the service?"

And that's precisely what I want to know!!! I've scoured the book and I don't see how to start up the service. The book actually seems to indicate that the service is called on start up. Maybe I've just misunderstood this part.

This is just experimental and I just want to see the service run and see the Log messages in logcat. The book says:"The system calls onCreate() when the service is first created, but before calling onStart(). This process, which resembles the process for creating an activity, provides a way for the service to perform one-time initialization at startup."

Well ok, but I'm not sure what to do to start the service except perhaps in my primary activity's onCreate() do something like:

```
    Intent TestService1 = new Intent(this,com.mydomain.myproject.TestService1.class);
    startActivity(TestService1);
```

But when I do this I get THE error: "The application ... has stopped unexpectedly."

I think this problem has a simple solution, but I'm just too simple to see it:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close. A service is not an activity, so you can't use `startActivity` to start it. Instead, use the similarly named [`startService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) method.

Comment: @Anomie thanks that got rid of the error, but why don't I see the Log message in logcat from at least the Service's onCreate() method? Ooops I see it now. It was there all along. Thanks.

Comment: @Anomie in "Pro Android 2" I found where it says how to start the thread: Context.startService(). And I found http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html where it also says Context.startService() too. But both give the following compile error:"Cannot make static reference to the non-static method startService(Intent) from the type Context." But startService() works ok. Why the confusing documentation?

Comment: @Marie: When you say `Context.startService`, you are trying to call a static (i.e. class) method named `startService`. When you say just `startService`, you are implicitly calling `this.startService` which is calling an instance method.

Comment: @Anomie I don't understand why the two sources of documentation above are both promoting Context.startService() as THE way to start a service. Both "Pro Android 2" and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html promote Context.startService() as THE way to start a Service. Why? How am I going to make progress using Services if the documentation is wrong? Before I get off topic should I ask a new question about the documentation?

Comment: @Marie: It's telling you to use the `startService` method declared in the Context class; otherwise, you might be left wondering where to find `startService`. I guess they expect you to check the documentation to find out whether it's static or instance and call it appropriately. Personally, I try to avoid such constructs in my writing to avoid people being confused as you are.

Comment: @Anomie I want to ask a new question about the confusing documentation as I have described above. Is that OK with you? Do you think I will get slammed, downvoted, and possibly banned?

Comment: @Marie: I doubt you would get banned. Depending on just what the question is and how you word it, a downvote is a possibility.